# Why must XML documents have a single root element?

Tags: xml, w3c

What is the motivation behind the decision to have a single root element in an XML document?

Could someone explain why the XML design team made this decision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/):

> Definition: There is exactly one element, called the root, or document element, no part of which appears in the content of any other element. [...] The elements, delimited by start- and end-tags, nest properly within each other.

Answer (score 5):

You're asking a design motivation question, which is ordinarily challenging to answer after-the-fact without merely speculating.

Fortunately, Tim Bray captured and recorded some of the [design history and motivations behind XML](https://www.xml.com/axml/axml.html), and says [this](https://www.xml.com/axml/notes/Nesting.html) regarding [*exactly one element, called the **root**, or document element*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-root):

> **Roots and Nests**
>
> This paragraph (which, strictly speaking is unnecessary - it is merely
>   amplifying the consequences of the grammar) describes the essence of
>   well-formedness. Simply stated, there has to be one element that
>   contains everything else, and all the elements have to nest nicely
>   within each other - no overlapping! All this "root" and "nest"
>   terminology suggests trees, which is just fine.
>
> The fact that XML requires a single root element is more important
>   than you might think; given that we expect to be transmitting these
>   documents over [network links](https://www.xml.com/axml/notes/Goal1.html) which, we all know, are sometimes
>   slow, flaky, and unreliable, it's a really good idea if the beginning
>   and (especially) the end of every document is clearly marked, so that
>   even if the guy on the other end is slow in closing down the link, you
>   know when you've got the whole message.

**See also:** [What is the difference between root node, root element and document element in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51025654/290085)

Comment: While interesting, since XML is by definition a subset of SGML, Tim Bray wasn't at liberty to change SGML's assumption to have a single document element. Actually, SGML has CONCUR which allows interleaved/overlapping tags from multiple DOCTYPEs in a single document instance to form multiple "views" (each having their own unique single document element) over an instance.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Wikipedia definition of XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)

> Extensible Markup Language (XML) is a markup language that defines a set of rules for encoding documents in a format that is both human-readable and machine-readable. The W3C's XML 1.0 Specification and several other related specifications—all of them free open standards—define XML.

Basically XML is a set of rules to make sure every document has the same standard. If you have a couple of hours to kill and wants to get bored to dead, you can read [the specification here](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/).

---

Back to your question, **it was a design decision to have only one root element in a document**.

One of the main advantage is to allows to build a [tree structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure). It's easier to parse a logical tree with a predefined structure then a collection of node of different types floating around.

With a predefined structure, it's also easier to traverse the document and find the information you're looking for.