# XPath returns for one element but doesn't return the other?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, dom4j

I am using Java to extract values using XPath. I was able to extract elements under the element `fields` but the elements under `records` are not returned.

XML is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <qdbapi>
        <action>****</action>
        <errcode>0</errcode>
        <errtext>No error</errtext>
        <qid>****</qid>
        <qname>****</qname>
      <table>
        <fields>            
        <field id="19" field_type="text" base_type="text">
        </field>
        </fields>
        <records>
        <record>
        <f id="6">1</f>
        </record>
        </records>
    </table>
  </qdbapi>
```

Code below:

```
XMLDOMDocObj.selectNodes("//*[local-name()='fields']")//21 fields returned
XMLDOMDocObj.selectNodes("//*[local-name()='records']")//no records are returned
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML must have a single root element; yours has two: `fields` and `records`.

Wrap them in a single common root to get the results you expect.

Also, if your XML has no namespaces, there's no reason to defeat them.  Instead of

```
//*[local-name()='records']
```

use

```
//records
```

See also

- [How does XPath deal with XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40796231/290085)
- [Why must XML documents have a single root element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56674356/290085)
- [What is the difference between root node, root element and document element in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51025654/290085)

Comment: And do both of your XPath's work for you now as predicted?

Comment: Only one of the Xpath values work namely 'fields' but the 'records' Xpath didnt work. Your suggestion for '//records' didn't work as well. For fields, the result is QBQueryResult:21 but for records the result is QBQueryResult:0. "QBQueryResult" is my result count

Comment: Works for me:   [`//*[local-name()='records']`](http://xpather.com/okqmVUE7)  (Click through to see.)

Comment: Yes, this worked!!! //*[local-name()='records']. However both did not work..//*[local-name()='records']/*[local-name()='record']. Also //*[local-name()='records']//record did not work. Xpath tester online returns no error. there are at-least 4 records under <records>

Comment: Both XPaths listed in my answer will work with your (corrected) XML.  So will `//records/record`.   Since your original problem is solved, I may I suggest that you accept this answer and post a new question with a complete [mcve] for any additional issues you're having?