# How to find file path for XML root

Tags: python, xml, windows, xml-parsing

In my python code I am using the `root = ElementTree.parse(known_file_path).getroot()` method to return an XML tree. I know the location of `known_file_path` (obviously), however, I cannot seem to determine where the "root" XML file is located on my filesystem. When I run `ElementTree.dump(root)` method I am able to see the contents of the XML file with all of the tags and information, and I just want to modify this file. However, I do not know where this file is stored, and I cannot seem to figure out how to print out the path to this file. Since Python is printing out tags and data, I should be able to find this XML file somewhere in my file system, right?

Comment: `root` is your main(first) tag in your xml file

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml

Answer (score 0):

[From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

> xml.etree.ElementTree.dump(elem)
> Writes an element tree or element structure to sys.stdout

So - `dump()` doesn't do what you expected it to do... For that you need

```
tree.write('output.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are under a misconception about what *root* means here.  It has nothing to do with a filesystem; it has to do with document structure.

### XML and document structure

The *root* (*root node*) of an XML document is the parent of the *root element* in an XML document.

See also [What is the difference between root node, root element and document element in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51025654/290085)

### Python and filesystems

If you want to get the filesystem path of an XML (or any other) file, see [How to get an absolute file path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51520/290085).