# SelectSingleNode relative to root node on passed XML

Tags: powershell, xpath, selectsinglenode

Given xml of

```
$xml = [Xml]@"
<Package>
    <Copy_Ex>
    </Copy_Ex> 
    <Move_Ex> 
        <Rules>
            <Rule>
                <Property>os</Property> 
                <Operator>-eq</Operator>
                <Value>Windows10</Value>
            </Rule>
        </Rules>
        <Task>
            <Rules>
                <Rule>
                    <Property>lastWriteTime</Property>                          
                    <Operator>-gt</Operator>
                    <Value>6W</Value>
                </Rule>
            </Rules>
        </Task>
    </Move_Ex>
</Package>
"@
```

I want to be able to select a single node from the xml, say `<Move_Ex>`, and pass it to a function, then independently access the two `<Rules>` nodes. I can do that now with

```
function Test {
    param (
        [Xml.XmlElement]$task
    )
    if ($nodeRules = $task.SelectSingleNode('//Rules')) {
        Write-PxXmlToConsole $nodeRules
    }
    if ($taskRules = $task.SelectSingleNode('//Task/Rules')) {
        Write-PxXmlToConsole $taskRules
    }
}
$task = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//Move_Ex')
Test $task
```

But `//` is searching the entire document, NOT just the `[Xml.XmlElement]` that I passed. So if I have a different `<Rules>` node in the `<Copy_Ex>` node, THAT is what gets returned by the first `SelectSingleNode()`. What I think I need is a way to identify the root node of the passed element, not the entire document. But I can't seem to find a way to do that consistently. My understanding is that while `//` finds the sequence of nodes anywhere in the document, `/` only finds it relative to the root node. Which should mean that

```
$task = $xml.SelectSingleNode('/Move_Ex')
```

finds only that `<Move_Ex>` in the root, and if I had another one somewhere else I would be fine. However, that doesn't return anything at all, which has me worried I don't really understand how either `/` or `//` works, which makes the chances of getting what I need to work unlikely.
I have looked at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement.getelementsbytagname?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_XmlElement_GetElementsByTagName_System_String_) for `[Xml.XmlElement]` and `GetElementsByTagName()` seems to be finding just the elements in my passed element. `Write-Host "$($task.GetElementsByTagName('Rules').Count)"` in the function returns a `2`, so not finding any `<Rules>` node I have put in `<Copy_Ex>`.
I also tried just dot referencing things, so

```
Write-PxXmlToConsole $task.Rules
Write-PxXmlToConsole $task.Task.Rules
```

And that seems to be working also. But again, ONLY when the element being passed is selected with `//` rather than `/`, and I worry that in a much more complex XML with hundreds of `<Rules>` nodes I won't be getting consistent results.

So, two questions...

1: What is the difference between `/` and `//` in this situation, and why isn't `/Move_Ex` working as "expected" in `$task = $xml.SelectSingleNode('/Move_Ex')`?

2: Is the dot referencing approach the "correct" way to limit my access to just the passed Element? Or is there another/better way?

I should note here that I did verify that `//` does break down if make the XML more realistic. So with this XML

```
$xml = [Xml]@"
<Package>
    <Copy_Ex>
        <Rules>
            <Rule>
                <Property>os</Property> 
                <Operator>-eq</Operator>
                <Value>WindowsXP</Value>
            </Rule>
        </Rules>
        <PreTask>
            <Move_Ex> 
                <Rules>
                    <Rule>
                        <Property>os</Property> 
                        <Operator>-eq</Operator>
                        <Value>WindowsVista</Value>
                    </Rule>
                </Rules>
                <Task>
                    <Rules>
                        <Rule>
                            <Property>lastWriteTime</Property>                          
                            <Operator>-gt</Operator>
                            <Value>8W</Value>
                        </Rule>
                    </Rules>
                </Task>
            </Move_Ex>
        </PreTask>
    </Copy_Ex> 
    <Move_Ex> 
        <Rules>
            <Rule>
                <Property>os</Property> 
                <Operator>-eq</Operator>
                <Value>Windows10</Value>
            </Rule>
        </Rules>
        <Task>
            <Rules>
                <Rule>
                    <Property>lastWriteTime</Property>                          
                    <Operator>-gt</Operator>
                    <Value>6W</Value>
                </Rule>
            </Rules>
        </Task>
    </Move_Ex>
</Package>
"@
```

Where I need to select only the `<Move_Ex>` in the `<Package>` node

```
$task = $xml.SelectSingleNode('/Move_Ex')
```

selects nothing, while

```
$task = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//Move_Ex')
```

selects the `<Move_Ex>` node nested in `<Copy_Ex>`, which is not at all what I want and need.

Note that all `Write-PxXmlToConsole` does is exactly that.

```
function Write-PxXmlToConsole ($xml) {
    $stringWriter = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter
    $xmlWriter = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextWriter $stringWriter
    $xmlWriter.Formatting = "indented"
    $xml.WriteTo($xmlWriter)
    $xmlWriter.Flush()
    $stringWriter.Flush()
    Write-Host $stringWriter.ToString()
    Write-Host
}
```

EDIT: With respect to my first question, and based on what @Prophet has already said, I realized I was conflating Root NODE and Root ELEMENT, and now I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025654/what-is-the-difference-between-root-node-root-element-and-document-element-in-x?rq=1) in my related links. Some good additional info about Root node, root element, document element, etc.

Comment: I'm a little confused: what exactly is your expected output from the "realistic" xml?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something or misunderstanding your question, but it seems to me that the answer is very simple:
The difference between `/` and `//`:
`/` will go to the direct child of the passed argument while `//` will look for any element below the passed argument.
By default XPath searches starting from the root node. This is why `'/Move_Ex'` returns nothing. There is no `Move_Ex` element directly below the root.
To start searching from current node, not from the root, you should put a dot `.` at the prefix of the XPath expression.
So, to get the `Rules` nodes inside the passed element you should use this XPath: `'//.Rules'`

Comment: I wonder if this is a PowerShell specific thing? I have never seen that approach mentioned before, and when I try it now I get `Exception calling "SelectSingleNode" with "1" argument(s): "'//.Rules' has an invalid token."` As for the root node, I think I am understanding better now. I THOUGHT package was the root node. But is it really that there is a root node, which can only contain one node, Package in this case? `$task = $xml.SelectSingleNode('/Package/Move_Ex')` seems to work as if that's the case. Also, `'./Rules'` seems to work as expected.

Comment: Interestingly, now that I can consistently get the right `<Rules>` node with `'./Rules'`, I just did a Measure-Command on a 1000 iteration loop, and it seems that dot notation is about twice as fast. Curious to see if that holds true or changes when dealing with very large XML files.

Comment: I have no idea if this is PowerShell issue. I do not familiar with PowerShell. I know, I hope, something about XPath. Package is really the root node here, but to select any other element using `/` you should define the path to it explicitly.  F.e. `/Package/Move_Ex` or, alternatively just `//Move_Ex`

Comment: I think on both counts PowerShell is doing something different. I think `./Rules` is how PS does it, to make it similar to relative path in the file system. And I am still not able to get `//Rules` to work. It doesn't find the rules in `<Package>`, it consistently finds the first `<Rules>`, so when I have one nested in `<Copy_Ex><PreTask>` it finds that. Only `$task = $xml.SelectSingleNode('/Package/Move_Ex')` finds the one in root, when root is specifically named. :( That said, it's not like MS is known for following standards, or being consistent. :)

Comment: Maybe it depends on method you are using to get the results? Again, I have no idea about PowerShell, I'm coming from Selenium world. So there, we have `findElement` method returning a single element. In case there are multiple elements on the page matching the passed locator it will return the first one, while `findElements` method will return a list containing all the matching elements.

Comment: So, did my answer resolved your problem or at least helped?

Comment: your answer definitely got me thinking, and led me to try `./Rules` which seems to be working. I would just love to have someone who knows the ins and outs of the PowerShell implementation chime in. I just don't trust Microsoft to not leave some surprises.